# (MatLab) Problem is unbounded when doing the linear programming in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

```
x + y ≤ 44,
2x + y ≤ 64,
9,000x + 5,000y ≤ 300,000
```

**objective function**: `30,000x + 20,000y`

I would like to find the Optimal solution in **Matlab**

But there are error message `Problem is unbounded.`

Here is my code

```
A = [1 1;2 1;9 5];

b = [44 64 300];

f = [3 2];

x = linprog(f,A,b)
```

suppose ans: `x=20,y=24`

**Reference**
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html

Comment: Because linprog minimizes and you want to maximize. You should negate f.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but one reason you're having difficulties is that you're using Matlab. Other languages would offer more expressive and easier-to-understand ways of expressing your problem.

Python for instance, coupled with [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) gives us:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable()
y = cp.Variable()

constraints = [
  x + y <= 44,
  2 * x + y <= 64
]

objective = cp.Maximize(9000*x + 5000*y)

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
N
optimum_value = prob.solve()

print("optimum value", optimum_value)
print("x", x.value)
print("y", y.value)
```

The code is very readable and the model is easily extended even to non-linear regimes such as quadratic programs and second-order cones.

This returns

```
optimum value 300000.00000076543
x 20.00000000075882
y 23.999999998787203
```